# get multiple EditText to work with an OnclickListener TextView, One result only at a time

Tags: button, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I am making an app the gets a user entered number and multiplies it 
by a number i set. there are 7 fields for the user to enter their number
each field **needs to be multiplied** **by a different number i pre set**. 
i only want to display one answer at a time with on button for answer FYI im a total noob!  this is what i have so far.
thanks,

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button b;
private EditText getCells;
private TextView getAns;
String s = "Answer";
double c = 0;

public Main2Activity() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convert);
    getCells = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seventyfive);
    getAns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ANSWER);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c = Double.parseDouble(getCells.getText().toString());
            s = Double.toString((c = ((c) * 1.2)));
            char ch[] = s.toCharArray();
            getAns.setText(ch, 0, ch.length);


        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What you want as output?

Comment: the answer to that math problem